# Is it safe ask password to user in an Android EditText?

Tags: android, string, security, passwords

Reading this blog, http://www.androidsecurity.guru/keep-sensitive-information-in-ram-for-a-short-time/, which has very interesting material, author encourages to use other method than EditText.

He says: "Following on from this, don’t use EditText which uses String in the underlying implementation.  Instead, use a View based on android.graphics.Canvas with a key listener accepting chars and assembling into char[]."

But getText() from EditText returns an Editable which has a getChars(). Is it really unsafe?

Comment: "But getText() from EditText returns an Editable which has a getChars()" -- all that does is make a copy of text from the `Editable` into `char[]` that you supply. "Is it really unsafe?" -- the opening words of the blog post that you cited are "For apps that need to be ultra-secure". Most apps do not need to be ultra-secure, even if they are collecting a passphrase from the user. If your threat vectors include people who might use heap dumps or something to get at the contents of an app's heap on a confiscated device, that would qualify as an app that needs to be "ultra-secure".

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe "ultra-secure" and "mobile phone" can't be in the same sentence...